# Azure queue receiving with python SDK: ValueError: could not convert string to float: max-age=31536000

Tags: python, azure

Now I am learning how to process real time data with Azure using python. The code is as below:

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService
from azure.servicebus import Message
import traceback

api_key = {'namespace': '###',
       'policy_name': '####',
       'policy_secret': '#####'
       }

sbs = ServiceBusService(api_key["namespace"], shared_access_key_name=api_key["policy_name"], shared_access_key_value=api_key["policy_secret"])

msg = Message('Hello World!')

while True:
    sbs.send_queue_message('taskqueue', msg)
    print 'sending done'
    try:
        msg_rcv = sbs.receive_queue_message('taskqueue', peek_lock=True)
        if msg_rcv and msg_rcv.body:
            print 'Message received: {0}'.format(msg_rcv.body)
            msg_rcv.delete()
    except Exception:
        print traceback.print_exc()
```

The sending part works fine, but I can not receive the queue correctly. The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "queue_sending.py", line 35, in <module>
  msg_rcv = sbs.receive_queue_message('taskqueue', peek_lock=True)
  ...
  ValueError: could not convert string to float: max-age=31536000
```

I googled around about this value error. The popular answer is that This is a bug in version 0.20.1. But the version of my `azure-servicebus` is 0.21.1. So for what I tried:

1. Downgrade `azure-servicebus` to 0.20.2.
2. Split the code into sender and receiver then run them separately.

Neither is working. Could someone give me a hint where I made a mistake? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed fixed in 0.20.2 (I did the fix :)). If you're 100% sure you have this bug in 0.21.1, please create an issue in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues with  the FULL stacktrace and some info like Python version, OS, etc.

(I own this package and work on MS)

Comment: You are right, it is still the version issue. My default python environment is Anaconda Python 2.7, whose latest `azure-service` version is 0.20.1. I compiled code in virtual environment under pure python 2.7, but I tested it under the global environment. It results in the failure. Now I test code in virenv, everything runs well.